# Crash in LicenseClientV3 (LicenseClientV3.java:248) - BadTokenException

Tags: android, exception, crashlytics

I'm getting this error in my Crashlytics, can't reproduce or find the cause, someone has any idea of what is going on?

I know what badTokenException means but I can't control LicenseClientV3.java to fix the issue, its not my class.

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@500b830 is not valid; is your activity running?
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:1153)
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:399)
       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:133)
       at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:345)
       at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1131)
       at com.pairip.licensecheck3.LicenseClientV3.lambda$showErrorDialog$2$com-pairip-licensecheck3-LicenseClientV3(LicenseClientV3.java:248)
       at com.pairip.licensecheck3.LicenseClientV3$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.run(:2)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

I have looked in Crashlytics registers before crash but cant take any insight about the problem with it.

Comment: Do you have Automatic integrity protection turned on in Google Play Console (Your app > Setup > App integrity > Automatic integrity protection > Enable automatic integrity protection for your app)?  We are seeing the same crash but did not notice it until enabling this setting.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this problem is to check if the activity is still running before displaying the dialog. This can be done by calling the **isFinishing()** method on the activity object
Here's an example of how to do this:

```
if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing()) {
            // show dialog here
        }
```

Another possible solution is to use the application **context instead of the activity context** to display the dialog. This can be done by calling getApplicationContext() instead of this or getContext() when creating the dialog
Here's an example of how to do this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setTitle("My Dialog");
    builder.setMessage("Hello, world!");
    builder.show();
```

Comment: Yes. But as I mentioned this class is not mine, its probably from BillingClient library. Then I cant change it, I cant even access this class `at com.pairip.licensecheck3.LicenseClientV3.lambda$showErrorDialog$2$com-pairip-licensecheck3-LicenseClientV3(LicenseClientV3.java:248)`. I've seen solutions related to BadTokenException but it's not gonna work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decompile the apk and remove the pairip protection

Answer (score 0):

The crash you were seeing was due to a bug in Automatic Integrity Protections by Play (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10183279?hl=en). This **bug has been fixed** and new versions of your app should not show this error in your Crashlytics dashboard.

In case you are still seeing this error or have any other issues with Automatic Integrity Protections, please report them via the Play Console or https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/gethelp.

Disclaimer: This is a response from the Play Integrity team.